# Ionic: Stacked and custom sized grid rows

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I'm very new to Ionic 2 and I'm facing a design problem with ion-grid.

I want to have three elements. On tablet or greater they should all be aligned in one row (side by side), but the first element should have a width of 80% and the other two a width of 10%.
On a smartphone the three rows should be stacked horizontally.

[image]

According to [the grid docu](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#-stacked-to-horizontal) `<ion-col col-12 col-sm>` can be used for the horizontal stacking and it is working.

Unfortunately I'm not able to achieve this 80/10/10 design. With `col-12 col-sm` the elements will be aligned with equal width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the [breakpoints](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#default-breakpoints) (eg. `col-md-8`). Combining a set of these you can set different column-width for different screen sizes.

In my example `col-12` means that the `<ion-col>` should have a column-width of 12 (full width) for the smallest screens. This rule will apply for all bigger screens unless there is another breakpoint is present. `col-md-8` makes the `<ion-col>` have a column-width of 12 on screen sizes with `min-width: 768px` and bigger.

**Example HTML:**

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12 col-md-8 style="background-color:blue; height:100px;"></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-12 col-md-2 style="background-color:green; height:100px;"></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-12 col-md-2 style="background-color:yellow; height:100px;"></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

**Result:**

Small screen:

[image]

Bigger screen:

[image]

My example uses the default number of columns per row which is 12. With this you can not achieve 80%/10%/10%-width for your columns. But you can change the number of columns per row to achieve this, see the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#customizing-the-grid) for more info.

Comment: Can anyone help me replicate this in Ionic 4 please?